# File corruption when inserting images to an existing word file

Tags: python-docx

The following code applied to an existing file works for 2 images but beyond the file is marked as corrupted (though it can be recovered perfectly in word):

```
import docx

docTemplate = "TestTemplate.docx"

# docx job: add test subsections + images
doc_docx = docx.Document(docTemplate)
#doc_docx = docx.Document()

p = doc_docx.add_paragraph()
wp = p.add_run()
wp.add_picture('image.png')
wp.add_break()
wp.add_picture('image.png')
wp.add_break()
wp.add_picture('image.png')

doc_docx.save('TestFile2.docx')
```

The content of `doc_docx.part.blob` is available [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hmY7mUQi)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the docTemplate document was already containing some objects. Thanks to the answer from @Tores76 on [python-docx github](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/455#issuecomment-357748310) I could solve the "file corruption" issue. This means it was likely due to a duplicate `docPr id`

```
# fix id
doc_element = doc_docx._part._element
docPrs = doc_element.findall('.//' + qn('wp:docPr'))
for docPr in docPrs:
    docPr.set('id',str(int(docPr.get('id'))+100000))
```